# Python script to replace characters in string with sequential integers?

Tags: python

I would like to create a script in Python to do the following:

take multiple lines of text:

```
&asdf01&  
&asdf01&  
&asdf01&  
&asdf01&  
&asdf01&  
&asdf01&  
&asdf01&  
&asdf01&  
&asdf01&  
&asdf01&  
&asdf01&
```

and replace as follows:

```
&asdf01&  
&asdf02&  
&asdf03&  
&asdf04&  
&asdf05&  
&asdf06&  
&asdf07&  
&asdf08&  
&asdf09&  
&asdf10&  
&asdf11&
```

Basically I need to replace consecutive characters in a string with a numerical value based off the line number of the string.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
If you were to make an honest solution attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 0):

This code should help you.

```
 strings = ['&asdf01&',  
'&asdf01&',  
'&asdf01&',  
'&asdf01&',  
'&asdf01&',  
'&asdf01&',  
'&asdf01&',  
'&asdf01&',  
'&asdf01&',
'&asdf01&', 
'&asdf01&'
]

for i, element in zip(range(1, len(strings)+1), strings):
    element = list(element)
    if i<10:
        element[-3] = '0'
    else:
        element[-3] = ''
    element[-2] = str(i)
    element = ''.join(element)
    strings[i-1] = element

print(strings)
```

**Output:**

['&asdf01&', '&asdf02&', '&asdf03&', '&asdf04&', '&asdf05&', '&asdf06&', '&asdf07&', '&asdf08&', '&asdf09&', '&asdf10&', '&asdf11&']

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little on what exactly you want to increment. Should it work for arbitrary structured input strings or can we assume to always have the pattern `&asdf01&`?.

This piece of code is kind of flexible and would increment the first 2 digits it does find in a string:

```
import re

def increment_digits(input_string):

  pattern = r'(\d{2})'
  match = re.search(pattern, input_string)

  if match:

    digits = match.group(1)
    increment = int(digits) + 1 
    zero_padded_increment = "{:02d}".format(increment)

    s = match.start(1)
    e = match.end(1)

    composed_string = input_string[:s] + zero_padded_increment + input_string[e:]
    return composed_string

  else:

    return input_string

in_list = [
  'Ihave20apples',
  'Ilike452people',
  'With99dollarsIbuy20iphones',
  '88abc99def0123xyz',
  '43',
  '0',
  'Hello',
  '&asdf01&']

for i in in_list:
  o = increment_digits(i)
  print("{:25s} -> {:25s}".format(i, o))
```

Result:

```
Ihave20apples             -> Ihave21apples
Ilike452people            -> Ilike462people
With99dollarsIbuy20iphones -> With100dollarsIbuy20iphones
88abc99def0123xyz         -> 89abc99def0123xyz
43                        -> 44
0                         -> 0
Hello                     -> Hello
&asdf01&                  -> &asdf02&
```